# Read specific code from XML

Tags: xml, vbscript

I'm not terribly familiar with reading through an XML file with VBS, so I need quite a bit of hand-holding. I can get as far as reading a basic XML file and getting the node name. However, I need to read through an XML file, check to see if a child node exists, if it does, read the value, and if it does not exist, create it. The code is below.

The node "ControllablePreferences" is always there, the child node "LocalLanAccess" may not be. I need to check if "LocalLanAccess" is there, if it is, what the value is, if it's not, I need to create it as True.

Any help anyone can provide is appreciated...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnyConnectPreferences>
    <DefaultUser>aUser</DefaultUser>
    <DefaultSecondUser></DefaultSecondUser>
    <ClientCertificateThumbprint>#############</ClientCertificateThumbprint>
    <ServerCertificateThumbprint></ServerCertificateThumbprint>
    <DefaultHostName>North America</DefaultHostName>
    <DefaultHostAddress></DefaultHostAddress>
    <DefaultGroup>#########</DefaultGroup>
    <ProxyHost></ProxyHost>
    <ProxyPort></ProxyPort>
    <SDITokenType>software</SDITokenType>
    <ControllablePreferences>
        <LocalLanAccess>true</LocalLanAccess>
    </ControllablePreferences>
```

EDIT *****

I was able to do it with the following code:

```
Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
sLocalAppData = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%LOCALAPPDATA%" )
sPrefFile = sLocalAppData & "\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility       client\preferences.xml"
sParentNode = "//ControllablePreferences"
sLocalLANAccess = "//ControllablePreferences/LocalLanAccess"

oXML.Async = false
oXML.load(sPrefFile)

If oXML.ParseError <> 0 Then
   WScript.Echo oXML.ParseError.Reason
   WScript.Quit 1
End If

If oXML.SelectNodes(sLocalLANAccess).Length = 0 Then
   WScript.Echo "Node missing."
   Set oRoot = oXML.selectsinglenode (sParentNode)
   Set oRecord = oXML.CreateElement("LocalLanAccess")
   oRoot.AppendChild oRecord
   Set oNode = oXML.selectsinglenode (sLocalLANAccess)
   oNode.text = "true"
   sResult = oXML.Save(sPrefFile)
   WScript.Echo "Updated preferences File"
Else
   Set oNode = oXML.selectsinglenode (sLocalLANAccess)
   if not oNode.Text = LCase("true") then
      oNode.text = "true"
      sResult = oXML.Save(sPrefFile)
      WScript.Echo "Updated preferences File"
   else
      WScript.Echo "Updated not required"
   End if
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to check is the presence of the node `<LocalLanAccess>`, something like this should do:

```vbs
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.Async = false
xml.Load "C:\path\to\your.xml"

If xml.ParseError <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo xml.ParseError.Reason
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

If xml.SelectNodes("//ControllablePreferences/LocalLanAccess").Length = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Node missing."
Else
  WScript.Echo "Node present."
End If
```

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Can you give me some constructive criticism? do I need all the sets??

Comment: @DaGbyte: You shouldn't post code in comments. Anything but simple one-liners usually becomes unreadable. If you used a different approach than what I proposed, you should post it as an answer of your own and accept that answer of yours.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my original post with my solution. Thanks for your help!